# Symfony Translation not work

Tags: php, twig, translation, symfony

I've override FosUser profile templates in `app/Resources/FosUserBundle`

Every thing is ok but translations not working!.

example:

in **`app/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml`** :

```
foo.bar: baz
```

in **`app/Resources/FosUserBundle/views/Profile/show_contect.html.twig`**

```
 {{ 'foo.bar' | trans }}  --> output: foo.bar
```

and there is no problem with locale: `app.request.locale` --> `en`

```
$ php bin/console debug:translation en
```

[image]

Comment: try to create `FOSUserBundle.en.yml` and put the file in `app/Resources/translations` then let me know. PS: I never used that bundle.

Comment: What is the locale your application is using when you get the wrong result? How does your locale related Symfony configuration look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has suggested by @gp_sflover symfony is not using the default messages catalog for manage the template, so you can add the new files `FOSUserBundle.en.yml` with the translation of force the trans filter to use the `messages` catalog as follow:

```
 {{ 'foo.bar' | |trans({}, 'messages') }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

As is [stated in documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations), you should place translation messages file `messages.en.yml` in folder `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations/`.